# What breaker size do I need to power radiant heat?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, radiant-heating

I am installing 4 set total of 240V radiant heat system behind 2 thermostats. Each thermostat will have 2, 240V, 168 ft², 8.4A, 2016W radiant heat systems mounted in parallel. The maximum power required is 4 x 2016W = 8064W to power all 4 systems, and the amperage is 8064W/240V = 33.6Amps.

Does that mean I need a breaker of 240V/50Amps? (33.6Amps/80% is 42 Amps)

Comment: Yes it does ....

Comment: Either that or have 2 circuits with 20 amps each

Comment: You may want to double-check the specs. Very, very often the units are sized to match common circuits - e.g., 8A (1/2 of continuous on a 20A), 12A (for 15A), 16A (for 20A), etc. The specs are also often based on 250V circuits, which actually can help a bit with the way the numbers work on a pure resistive circuit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sort of thing is normally done with two separate 20A circuits, where the load is 16A or less per circuit, but you have some oddball heat units **just enough bigger** (that extra 0.4A per heater) that would require 21A derated; So, four 15A circuits would make more sense.

- The wiring is (much) less expensive
- The fault current in case of a fault is much less
- The heat is exactly the same.

Controlling more than one heat circuit with one thermostat is normally handled by using relays controlled by the thermostat to control individual 15A circuits (in your case.) However, line voltage thermostats are inexpensive enough that providing one thermostat per circuit is also a common approach, and permits "zoning" the heat easily.

Comment: Thank you @Ecnerwal

Comment: Could you tell me more about how the relays work? What is their purpose?

Comment: To control two separate circuits (which must stay separate) from one thermostat, the relay allows the thermostat (on one of the circuits, or on its own circuit) to switch other circuits while keeping them separated. So the thermostat calls for heat by energizing the relay coil (at 24, 120, or 240VAC - thermostat and relay coil voltage must match) and the relay contacts (which are electrically isolated from the  coil) close to energize the heat circuit associated. Multiple relay coils can be energized by one thermostat at the same time.

Comment: That is helpful, thank you.  Are you suggesting that 2 heating system behind one thermostat would not work without relay? I don't need zoning, don't need two thermostats, and still not clear why both heating system "must" be on separate circuits. What would happen if no relay is used and both heating system are connected together to one thermostat fed by a 240v circuit?

Comment: Without a relay, you'd need a 25A rated thermostat and 10Ga wire on a 25A circuit breaker for each pair. 10Ga wire is typically more than twice the cost of 14Ga, as well as being more difficult to handle (it's larger and stiffer.) But sure, if you want to spend your money that way, go ahead. Relays are the standard way of handling it, and keep the circuits smaller, less expensive, and more easily run.

Comment: Thank you Ecnerwal. What I was missing is that I would need a 25A rated thermostat. From research, most radiant heat thermostats are rated for 16A and do accept 2 radiant heat systems (cables) without relay.  In terms of cost, cable cost are variable depending on length, thermostat cost is fix. In my case, cable cost is not a problem as cables are small and therefoer much cheaper than the cost of a thermostat. That said, I cannot find a 25A rated thermostat with sensors and smart.

Comment: > "Without a relay, you'd need a 25A rated thermostat and 10Ga wire on a 25A circuit breaker for each pair." Hi Ecnerwal, is the relay on the power side (before) of the thermostat or on the heating cable side (after) the thermostat. If the relay allows me to use a 16A thermostat then it must be before, what am I missing?

Comment: You appear to be missing that, with a relay, the thermostat is switching typically a few milli-Amperes to operate the relay coils, and the relay contacts are switching the power to the heaters. Or the thermostat is switching one heater at 8.4A, plus a few milliamperes for the relay coil that switches the other heater circuit with its contacts.

Comment: Yes, but if the power source is 25A then how does the relay allow me to use a 16A thermostat? Power is plugged into the thermostat, then thermostat is powering the relay, then the relay powers the (2) 8.4A heating cables. So with relay or not, I still need a 25A thermostat, no?

Comment: A sub one-amp thermostat and a 25A (or greater) relay would do, if you insist on the 25A setup. The relay contacts switch the power. The thermostat switches only the relay coil.

Comment: Hi Ecnerwal, I am still ramping up on all this knowledge. What is a "one-amp" thermostat?
For my own understanding, If I were to use a relay: The relay has (1) input (25A), and (2) output (8.4A). The thermostat is connected to the relay to switch on the relay coil. What is powering the thermostat?